# Send option-tag from HTML to Flask using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to send an option tag the client choose, and process it into Python-Flask. This is what I've tried by now:

interactive.html

```
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js?version=3"></script>
    <script type=text/javascript>
        $(function() {
            $('a#process_input').bind('click', function() {
                $.getJSON('/background_process', {
                    select_classifier: $('input[name="select_classifier"]').val(),
                }, function(data) {
                    $("#result").text(data.result);
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <span>Please choose the option:</span>
            <select name="select_classifier">
                {% for o in data %}
                    <option value="{{ o.name }}">{{ o.name }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
</body>
```

python file:

```
@app.route('/interactive', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def function():
    return render_template('interactive.html',
                           data=[{'name': 'option1'},
                                 {'name': 'option2'},
                                 {'name': 'option3'},])

@app.route('/background_process', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def background_process():
    classifier = request.args.get('select_classifier', 0, type=str)
    print(classifier)
```

This print will give me the value 0, but what I was expected was option1, option2 or option3 which I chose. Which seems to be the problem here? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jQuery is trying to find the value of `input[name="select_classifier"]`, but the element is not an input, it is a select. Try `select[name="select_classifier"]` instead.